# MOSFET damage bad gate drivers?

Tags: mosfet

I've got a speed controller (VESC) I changed some blown MOSFETs on.
Is it safe to test without trying to replace the gate drivers also?
What damage could happen to the new MOSFETs if the gate drivers are bad?
I can connect the speed controller to 84 V and turn it on (zero output) without any sparks.

Comment: Could you please expand on the description of your problem? Perhaps upload a clear image, or any schematic diagram if you are able to find it. Show some progress and elemental research before asking for help.

Comment: it's a simple question, what happens to mosfets if you try and run them with bad gate drivers

Comment: Can you define bad gate driver? Is output; 1 Nothing (open), 2 full voltage (closed), 3 overvoltage, 4 undervoltage?

Comment: Failures tend to cascade, yes it is possible; more importantly, you should find ways to test and identify failures without having to blindly replace.

Comment: I can't figure out how to test the output of this VESC without actually running it.  I've got an oscilloscope.  I don't know if the gates are bad, someone told me if a mosfet blew, the gates are probably bad also.  There are some very tiny caps or resistors right beside the driver gates, it will be a challenge to replace them without disturbing things.

Comment: https://github.com/vedderb/bldc-hardware

Comment: Often when MOSFETs fail, the gate is shorted to source too. I’ve encountered one so far which burned off the bond wires to the gate connection completely, effectively opening the gate. Hook up your oscilloscope to measure Vgs and Vds during switching. Is your PCB identical to the one linked? Is there no ground plane?

Comment: @embededfabrication then a simple answer: if the drivers AND the MOSFETS are shorted = boom + magic smoke. If the drivers are shorted = magic smoke AND likely damage to the MOSFETS (hence more boom).

Comment: Ya, I ordered news gates, I better put them on then.  There must be a way to test these speed controllers without putting a lot of current through them

Answer (score 1):

If the mosfets shorted the gate to the drain then they could have sent the full drain voltage to the gate. If the driver voltage could not tolerate the gate voltage (if it was significantly higher) then its possible that the gate drivers  could be damaged. If so replace it.